# Vector Graphics Illustrator

Tags: graphics

I am sorry if this is not the right place, but I didn't know where else to ask and I can't find an acceptable answer anywhere online.

I'm considering getting a tablet and would really prefer an Android.  However, the most critical requirement for me is the vector graphics illustrator.  I am a mathematician and make a lot of drawings for presentations and papers using Inkscape (an open source version of Adobe Illustrator).  The iPad has an app called Inkpad (which is not the same as Android's Inkpad), which is just like Inkscape, only it also allows the user to draw a curve freehand and convert it to a Bezier curve.

I was wondering if there was anything similar for Android and if so, how it compares in functionality and image quality to Inkscape/Inkpad for iPad.

Thank you!

Comment: See if [AutoCAD WS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autodesk.autocadws) suits you.

Comment: Did you look in the [Play Store](http://play.google.com)?

Answer (score 3):

There is an application called **Infinite Design** available in both free & paid versions. It will allow you to export to SVG for editing in your favorite graphics editor. It's been tested and works in Adobe Illustrator and Inkscape (paid version only).

- Free Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brakefield.idfree
- Paid Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brakefield.id

Another application is called **Simplector**, again available in both free & paid (pro) versions:

- Free Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=plasma.vector.editor.app
- Pro Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=plasma.vector.editor.app.pro

I cannot comment on the functionality & image quality compared to similar iPad applications.